# How to keep GoogleAPIClient always connected

Tags: android, location, google-play-services, google-api-client

I am using GoogleAPIClient to read location information. I want this to be always connected. How to ensure that it is always connected. One way is to reconnect it whenever connection failure callbacks are invoked.

What are the use-case at which below callbacks are triggered?
1.OnConnectionFailedListener -> onConnectionFailed 
2. ConnectionCallbacks -> onConnectionSuspended

I tried force stopping google play services but did not get callback [onConnectionSuspended]

Will there be any issue (battery, performance) if GoogleAPIClient is always connected?

Comment: What do you mean always connected?.

Comment: Always connected means never disconnect it.. It will be connected even if app is in background

Answer (score 0):

From the official documentation you can find the following:

```
// Create an instance of GoogleAPIClient.
if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
     mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
         .addConnectionCallbacks(mConnectionCallbacks)
         .addOnConnectionFailedListener(mConnectionFailedCallbacks)
         .addApi(LocationServices.API)
         .build();
}
//you will need to specify the callbacks.

//Of course, you will need to connected:
protected void onStart() {
     mGoogleApiClient.connect();
     super.onStart();
}

//Disconnect
protected void onStop() {
     mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
     super.onStop();
}

//get last location
public Location getLastLocation(){
//you need to be connected. Therefore this must be in the onConnected
//method of the mConnectionCallbacks.
     mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(
            mGoogleApiClient);
}
```

Link: [Getting the Last Known Location](https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html)

**EDIT**:
The only use case for having it connected (or the only I know) is for when you want to have a service that tracks your location even when the app is in the background.

Read here some interesting tutorials about this: 
http://www.101apps.co.za/articles/services-tutorials-part-2-a-foreground-service.html

http://www.edureka.co/blog/android-tutorials-beginners-service-component/ 
**Edit 2**

Links for details about failed connection: 
1. [onConnectionFailed](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener#public-method-summary) 
2. [Accessing the Google Api](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/api-client#start_an_automatically_managed_connection)

Comment: My question is, how can we have it always connected. I don't want to disconnect it in onStop... What are the issues if we keep it always connected? When do we get connection suspension/disconnection callbacks? Any use-cases?

Comment: Well if you want to use this for tracking your location every time you can use a service and via the service have this started/stopped accordingly to the status of the service. So, if you have an entity that can still receive location updates it makes sense to have it connected otherwise not.

Comment: Even with service the problem here will not be solved. I am not sure when GoogleAPIClient failure callbacks will be invoked.

Comment: Why you need to be sure when the failure will be invoked? You need to connect, keep it connected, have in mind that the problem might appear, have a generic solution until you know more and a call to disconnect when the service stops.

Comment: I want to reconnect it in case of failure.. I need some callback when it is failed. I can not rely on Service Destroy. It may possible that failure has occurred and service is still running.

Comment: Man, everything is in the answer above. You have a failed connection callback. Why it happens, check the documentation for details. As a starting point I attached some links from the official documentation, things that you can also check for yourself.

Comment: Thanks. If you can see my question, I am asking about when these callbacks are triggered. I want to test that use-case. I am already aware of information which you have provided.